# How to make buttons fixed position

Tags: html, css

HTML code there are some other button they are changing there places

```
    <div id="Visibility" class="dropdown">
    <button class="tablinks">Visibility <span style='font-size:14px;'>&#9662;</span></button>
```

#css

```
        <style>
      #tablinks{
           position: fixed;
      }
        </style>
```

Comment: `#tablinks` would select an element with the _ID_ `tablinks`, but your button has a _class_ of that name.

Comment: How should i mention the tablinks in css.